# Do multiple jdbc input run simultaneously or sequentially?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I need to query multiple database instances and I wanted to know when defining multiple jdbc input plugins in just 1 pipeline is the exact same thing (technically) as defining multiple pipelines with 1 jdbc input each ?

When running Logstash with mutilple jdbc input plugins, are they querying databases in a simultaneous way (concurrently) or are they querying sequentially ?
And what about performance, what would be better, multiple pipelines with the same config (except for the jdbc URL) or multiple jdbc input plugins in just 1 pipeline ?

**Note:** I'm using Logstash 6.2

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's a way to perform the input sequentially.

But the option schedule from the jdbc input can reduce the frequency of the queries, in order to avoid the SESSIONS_PER_USER limit.

As it is: `schedule => "* * * * *"`, your plugin will connect to the db every minute ([see here](https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*_*_*)). You can use instead `schedule => "*/15 * * * *"`, which will connect every 15 minutes ([see here](https://crontab.guru/#*/15_*_*_*_*)).

Comment: It does not answer my question,  just wanted to know if we put many jdbc input plugins in one pipeline, will they run in parallel or in a sequence mode ?